# Connect piano digital keyboard to 5.1 surround speakers

Tags: digital-piano, speakers

I have these 5.1 speakers system which can be connected with a minijack 3.5mm Line IN and a digital piano ([Yamaha P-105](https://usa.yamaha.com/products/musical_instruments/pianos/p_series/p-105/)) which has the following ports:

in the back:

[image: in the back]

in the front (for phones):
[image]

now I would like to connect the speakers to the piano so that the piano will be the input device and the speakers will play the output.

What options do I have?

If you give me a list of options I can see if I'm lucky and find some cable / device in my house, so I won't need to buy other stuff.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Two cables from the keyboard's Aux L and Aux R outputs, combining to a single TRS 'stereo' mini-jack plug.

You may have a stereo mini-jack to 2 phono plugs cable lying around.  This is the standard computer 'soundcard cable' that connects computer audio output to a domestic hi-fi system.  Add a couple of phono > 1/4" jack plug adapters.

[image]

[image]